# Is Poe not spelling Hux in Aubresh?

Tags: star-wars, languages, the-last-jedi

At the beginning of TLJ, Poe stalls the First Order’s attack by pretending to have a bad connection:

> **Poe:** Hux?
>
> **Hux:** He can?
>
> **Poe:** **With an ‘H’?** Skinny guy? Kind of pasty?
>
> **Hux:** I can hear you. Can you hear me?

**Shouldn't h in [Aurabesh](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aurebesh) be with a ‘[herf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tRAf.png)’, not with an ‘aitch’?**

Comment: Good question. Obviously the out-of-universe reason is that only 0.01% of the movie-going population have a clue what Aurabesh is, let alone the 0.01% of those who know how to pronounce certain letters.

Comment: Good question but you might as well ask why all the movie dialog isn't in Galactic Basic and the audience isn't subjected to an entire movie full of subtitles. If a semi-in-universe answer is that all the dialog is dubbed into English (or whatever the native language is where the film is being shown) then the dubbing would substitute ‘herf’ with an ‘aitch’. It might be interesting to see what that line was dubbed as in a language other than English.

Comment: FYI:  The subtitles reveal that Poe is saying “Hugs” instead of “Hux”.

Answer (score 6):

You're watching a film "translated" into English. As such, and since Aurabesh has a 1:1 correlation with the English alphabet, "herf" and "aitch" are the same thing.

Comment: While I think this is reasonable assumption, I am not aware of any canon reference that Star Wars is "translated". Most sources consider aurabesh to be a _writing_ system (alphabet), not a spoken language necessarily. Do you have a reference to cite noting that the movies are "translated"?

Comment: @Mufasa, given that the characters are speaking Galactic Basic, which has its own history and influences from alien species (https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Basic_Standard), it's pretty much safe to assume it is not, in fact, "really" English.